# Custom Template not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, themes

I am very new user of WordPress. I am trying to create a WordPress theme but a custom template not working. Its showing --Not Found
The requested URL /wordpresstheme/resources/ was not found on this server.

I created a page name after -- page-resources.php

MY code is

```
<?php 
    /*
        Template Name: Resources Page

    */

 get_header();?>
```

I selected it from my admin page panel and not working the default template also.

Please help me.

Comment: Would highly recommend reading the documentation thoroughly https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the very simple answer of this problem--

click: WAMP icon->Apache->Apache modules->chose rewrite_module

Answer (score 0):

Try this example, and adjust for you:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Contributor Page
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<?php
    if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
        // Include the featured content template.
        get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
    }
?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            ?>

            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <?php
                    the_title( '<header class="entry-header"><h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1></header><!-- .entry-header -->' );

                    // Output the authors list.
                    twentyfourteen_list_authors();

                    edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyfourteen' ), '<footer class="entry-meta"><span class="edit-link">', '</span></footer>' );
                ?>
            </article><!-- #post-## -->

            <?php
                    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                        comments_template();
                    }
                endwhile;
            ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: Yes I tried it but not working but my home page is still working well that is named after page-home.php

Comment: Hey, I solved the problem. It was the problem about Apache rewrite module. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Wordpress admin dashboard and re-save/update your permalinks.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<?php 
/*
    Template Name: Blog Home
*/
get_header();
?>
This is template page
<? php get_footer(); ?>`
```